# OptaPlanner for large data sets

Tags: optaplanner

I have been asked by a customer to work on a project using Drools. Looking at the Drools documentation I think they are talking about OptaPlanner.

The company takes in transport orders from many customers and links these to bookings on multiple carriers. Orders last year exceeded 100,000. The "optimisation" that currently takes place is based on service, allocation and rate and is linear (each order is assigned to a carrier using the constraints but without any consideration of surrounding orders). The requirement is to hold non-critical orders in a pool for a number of days and optimize the orders in the pool for lowest cost using the same constraints.

Initially they want to run "what if's" over last year's orders to fine-tune the constraints. If this exercise is successful they want to use it in their live system.

My question is whether OptaPlanner is the correct tool for this task, and if so, if there is an example that I can use to get me started.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [vehicle routing videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLJY69IMbAdq0uKPnjtWXZ2x7KE1eWg3ns), as it sounds like you have a vehicle routing problem.

If you use just Drools to assign orders, you basically build a Construction Heuristic (= a greedy algorithm). If you use OptaPlanner to assign the orders (and Drools to calculate the quality (= score) of a solution), then you get a better solution. See [false assumptions on vehicle routing](http://www.jboss.org/optaplanner/blog/2013/08/06/FalseAssumptionsForVRP.html) to understand why.

To scale to 100k orders (= planning entities), use [Nearby Selection](http://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2015/01/27/ScalingVehicleRoutingAndTSPWithNearbySelection.html) (which is good up to 10k) and Partitioned Search (which is [a sign of weakness](http://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2014/03/03/CanMapReduceSolvePlanningProblems.html) but needed above 10k).

Comment: Compliments Geoffrey for the great work, I wonder if the scaling to 100K is really an issue for Mark's problem. Since his customer will never get so many order simultaneously, the size of the problem is reduced (orders already delivered cannot be further optimized). Even the analysis of past year orders should be performed considering the order arrivals.

Comment: Good point - the size of the past year orders doesn't matter during solving (any influence can be precalculated). Only size of the number of orders to plan matters.